# Need to get rid of attachment in an email sent through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I have written a code to send an inline image in a mail through asp.net.

I am getting the image inside the email, but additionally, i am also getting attachment of the image with .bin format.

How can i get rid of this attachment?

This attachment appears in all email programs (mobile, owa, microsoft outlook 2016)

The attachment comes with name AT00001.bin

Below is the code

```
    protected void UBR_HNC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SmtpClient smtpClnt;
        MailMessage objMail;

        // Prepare Email  
        // Load Email Template from HTML File. 
        //String sHTMLbody = string.Empty;

        // Send Email
        // Create new Mail Object
        objMail = new MailMessage(); // Create new Mail Object
        objMail.From = new MailAddress("santoshkumar_g@abc.com");
        objMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("santoshkumar_g@abc.com"));

        objMail.Subject = "UBR Delivery HNC";

        objMail.AlternateViews.Add(Mail_Body());
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;


        // Open SMTP Connection to Mail Server and send email.
        smtpClnt = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClnt.Host = "10.98.134.29";
        smtpClnt.Port = Convert.ToInt16("25");
        smtpClnt.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClnt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        smtpClnt.Send(objMail);

        smtpClnt.Dispose(); // Close the SMTP Mail server connection.
        objMail.Dispose(); // Clear the mail object
    }    

private AlternateView Mail_Body()    
{

    LinkedResource imageResource = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/images/UBR_Delivery_L2_HNCmail.png"));
    imageResource.ContentId = "HDIImage";
    string str = @"  
         <tr>  
                <td>  
                  <image src=cid:HDIImage  id='img' alt=''/>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    AlternateView AV =
    AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    AV.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
    return AV;
}
```

Comment: Show the full code that attaches the file and sends the mail

Comment: Hi Caius sure i will add the code

Comment: Are those commented out lines supposed to be active?

Comment: private AlternateView Mail_Body()
    {
        //string path = Server.MapPath(@"images/UBR_Delivery_L2_HNC.png");
        LinkedResource imageResource = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/images/UBR_Delivery_L2_HNCmail.png"));
        imageResource.ContentId = "HDIImage";
        string str = @"  
              
            ";
        AlternateView AV =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        AV.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
        return AV;
    }

Comment: Hi Caius, no need to uncomment those lines, mail_body method is shared in the above comment, as it was not allwing me to add when i am trying to add that part of code in this site, so sharing you in comment

Comment: So when I said "show the full code" :) ... Please put that commented code in the question body too

Comment: and the attachment in the email is comming with a name ATT00001.bin

Comment: I understand Cais, i was trying to put the above method in question too, but it is saying code not properly formatted. thats why i shared you as comment

Comment: For posting code, every line needs to start with 4 blank spaces. Perhaps also clean it up so it's the bare minimum set of lines to repro the problem- more polite than asking us to wade through tens of extra lines of commented out attempts. Final q; does this bin attachment show in all email programs (your phone, your gmail, your outlook) etc or does it only show in some email programs ?

Comment: Hi Caius, able to add that missing code in the question now, yes Caius this attachment shows in all email programs mobile, outlook web app, microsoft outlook

Comment: And one more thing to add to it is, the image file appears in mobile, outlook web app, but doesnt appear in microsoft outlook 2016  . i have tried many things like unchecking the download in trust settings but of no help, i am referring to the inline image, which is appearing in the email

Comment: Hi Caius, now i am able to format the  complete code properly and added to the question, thanks for that. let me know once you find any solution from your side for the above issue thanks.